# In React, does a return statement return immediately or does it wait for the UseEffect to finish?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am following a Youtube tutorial in which I am building a full stack Instagram clone with Firebase v8. I am having trouble understanding the following Custom Hook in which we are checking if the user is already logged in:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import FirebaseContext from "../context/firebase";

export default function useAuthListener() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authUser"))
  );
  const { firebase } = useContext(FirebaseContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        // we have a user...therefore we can store the user in localstorage
        localStorage.setItem("authUser", JSON.stringify(authUser));
        setUser(authUser);
      } else {
        // we don't have an authUser, therefore clear the localstorage
        localStorage.removeItem("authUser");
        setUser(null);
      }
    });

    return () => listener();
  }, [firebase]);

  return { user };
}
```

So we are checking if the user is logged in to conditionally render some components.

My question: Suppose I call this Hook in my `Home.js` component, AND there is already a user in the local storage, then does this hook immediately return that user or does it wait for the `useEffect` hook to run and get info from the firebase server? Also, is there a need to pass `firebase` in the dependency array [since `firebase` is a constant]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way, 'user' will always be returned first and only then the code in `useEffect` will run.

I quote the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

> ... `useEffect` will run after the render is committed to the screen.

In a shorter and simpler statement: `useEffect` runs only after the component finished rendering its JSX.

You don't need to add 'firebase' because you've already created a listener that will cause 'user' state to alter, thus re-rendering your DOM again (AND creating a new listener again).